# Billboarded sprites stop working if moved from 0,0,0

Tags: java, math, opengl

I got this code for billboarding I created (With the help of others, and a nehe tutorial), but it seems that when I move my sprites from 0,0,0 it stops working correctly, for example the closer I get to a sprite that's at 50,0,50 the more sideways it gets.

Any idea how to make the sprites billboard properly when not on 0,0,0?

Here is the code:

```
public void drawBillBoardSprite(Texture texture, Vector3f sprPos, float r, float g, float b, int sprWidth, int sprHeight){
         // store the current model matrix
        GL11.glPushMatrix();

            // bind to the appropriate texture for this sprite
            texture.bind();
            Vector3f look = new Vector3f(0,0,0);
            Vector3f.sub(player.pos, sprPos, look);
            look.normalise();

            Vector3f right = new Vector3f(0,0,0);
            Vector3f.cross(new Vector3f(0,1,0) /* <-- default up vector */, look, right);
            right.normalise();

            Vector3f up = new Vector3f(0,0,0);
            Vector3f.cross(look, right, up);
            up.normalise();


            Matrix4f m = new Matrix4f();
            m.m00 = right.x;
            m.m01 = right.y;
            m.m02 = right.z;
            m.m03 = 0;

            m.m10 = up.x;
            m.m11 = up.y;
            m.m12 = up.z;
            m.m13 = 0;

            m.m20 = look.x;
            m.m21 = look.y;
            m.m22 = look.z;
            m.m23 = 0;

            m.m30 = sprPos.x;
            m.m31 = sprPos.y;
            m.m32 = sprPos.z;
            m.m33 = 1;

            java.nio.FloatBuffer fb = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(32);
            m.store(fb);
            fb.flip();
            GL11.glMultMatrix(fb);

            // draw a quad textured to match the sprite
            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0);                                     GL11.glVertex3f( - (sprWidth/2), (sprHeight/2), 0);    // Top left Of The Quad (Left)
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(texture.getWidth(), 0);                   GL11.glVertex3f( + (sprWidth/2), (sprHeight/2), 0);  // Top right Of The Quad (Left)
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight()); GL11.glVertex3f( + (sprWidth/2), -(sprHeight/2), 0);   // Bottom right Of The Quad (Left)
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, texture.getHeight());                  GL11.glVertex3f( - (sprWidth/2), -(sprHeight/2), 0);   // Bottom left Of The Quad (Left)
            GL11.glEnd();

        // restore the model view matrix to prevent contamination
        GL11.glPopMatrix();

    }
```

Edit: tried this code based on Knetic's answer, but it didn't even rotate the sprites towards the camera. Here is the code I used:

```
public void drawBillBoardSprite(Texture texture, Vector3f sprPos, float r, float g, float b, int sprWidth, int sprHeight){
         // store the current model matrix
        GL11.glPushMatrix();
            FloatBuffer tempViewBuf = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);

            GL11.glGetFloat(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, tempViewBuf);

            float[] tempView = new float[16];

            for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
                tempView[i] = tempViewBuf.get(i);
            }

            float[] modelView = new float[6];

            modelView[0] = tempView[0] - tempView[1];
            modelView[1] = tempView[0] + tempView[1];

            modelView[2] = tempView[4] - tempView[5];
            modelView[3] = tempView[4] + tempView[5];

            modelView[4] = tempView[8] - tempView[9];
            modelView[5] = tempView[8] + tempView[9];

            // bind to the appropriate texture for this sprite
            texture.bind();

            // draw a quad textured to match the sprite
            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0);                                     GL11.glVertex3f( - (sprWidth/2) + modelView[1], (sprHeight/2) + modelView[3], 0 + modelView[5]);    // Top left Of The Quad (Left)
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(texture.getWidth(), 0);                   GL11.glVertex3f( + (sprWidth/2) + modelView[0], (sprHeight/2) + modelView[2], 0 + modelView[4]);  // Top right Of The Quad (Left)
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight()); GL11.glVertex3f( + (sprWidth/2) + modelView[1], -(sprHeight/2)+ modelView[3], 0 + modelView[5]);   // Bottom right Of The Quad (Left)
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, texture.getHeight());                  GL11.glVertex3f( - (sprWidth/2) + modelView[0], -(sprHeight/2)+ modelView[2], 0 + modelView[4]);   // Bottom left Of The Quad (Left)
            GL11.glEnd();

        // restore the model view matrix to prevent contamination
        GL11.glPopMatrix();

    }
```

Comment: If I am reading that correctly, when you actually draw your sprite, your references are not based off of the current sprite location, but simply its size + the origin. Is that correct?

Comment: yeah, I found the sprites actually moved around when the camera moved if I used the sprite positions to draw them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to use a different way of billboarding:

```
public void drawBillBoardSprite(Texture texture, Vector3f sprPos, float r, float g, float b, int sprWidth, int sprHeight){
         // store the current model matrix
        GL11.glPushMatrix();
            GL11.glTranslatef(sprPos.x, 0, sprPos.z);
            // bind to the appropriate texture for this sprite
            texture.bind();

            FloatBuffer modelview = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);

            // get the current modelview matrix
            GL11.glGetFloat(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);

            // Note that a row in the C convention is a column 
            // in OpenGL convention (see the red book, pg.106 in version 1.2)
            // right vector is [1,0,0]  (1st column)
            // lookAt vector is [0,0,1] (3d column)
            // leave the up vector unchanged (2nd column)
            // notice the increment in i in the first cycle (i+=2)
            for(int i=0; i<3; i+=2 ) 
                for(int j=0; j<3; j++ ) {
                    if ( i==j )
                        modelview.put(i*4+j, 1.0f);
                    else
                        modelview.put(i*4+j, 0.0f);
                }

            // set the modelview matrix
            GL11.glLoadMatrix(modelview);

            // draw a quad textured to match the sprite
            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0);                                     GL11.glVertex3f( - (sprWidth/2), (sprHeight/2), 0);    // Top left Of The Quad (Left)
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(texture.getWidth(), 0);                   GL11.glVertex3f( + (sprWidth/2), (sprHeight/2), 0);  // Top right Of The Quad (Left)
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight()); GL11.glVertex3f( + (sprWidth/2), -(sprHeight/2), 0);   // Bottom right Of The Quad (Left)
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, texture.getHeight());                  GL11.glVertex3f( - (sprWidth/2), -(sprHeight/2), 0);   // Bottom left Of The Quad (Left)
            GL11.glEnd();

        // restore the model view matrix to prevent contamination
        GL11.glPopMatrix();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I dug up an old project of mine which had billboarded particles, and my solution was this.

```
static float[] tempView;

// ...additional render stuff up here

// If there's anything that needs billboarding
if(getParticleTop() > 0)
{
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, tempView);

modelView[0] = tempView[0] - tempView[1];
modelView[1] = tempView[0] + tempView[1];

modelView[2] = tempView[4] - tempView[5];
modelView[3] = tempView[4] + tempView[5];

modelView[4] = tempView[8] - tempView[9];
modelView[5] = tempView[8] + tempView[9];

// ... render each particle
}
```

And in the individual particle renders

```
float* modelView = renderer->getModelView();

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
{
glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
glVertex3f(owner->x - (modelView[1] * scale), owner->y - (modelView[3] * scale), owner->z - (modelView[5] * scale));

glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
glVertex3f(owner->x + (modelView[0] * scale), (owner->y + modelView[2] * scale), owner->z + (modelView[4] * scale));

glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
glVertex3f(owner->x + (modelView[1] * scale), owner->y + (modelView[3] * scale), owner->z + (modelView[5] * scale));

glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
glVertex3f(owner->x - (modelView[0] * scale), owner->y + (modelView[2] * scale), owner->z - (modelView[4] * scale));
}
glEnd();
```

Looking on it now, i see that i wasn't precaching scalar calculation and was using GL_QUADS instead of unrolling it myself, but i do know this works with all angles and all sizes.

I remember going through NeHe's tutorial and finding the same problem, this solution gave up on NeHe and googled out someone else who suggested the GL modelview method, which saves calculations (and time, if your video architecture is close enough to your processor).

I hope this helps.

EDIT; I should have mentioned, but the layout i used in this project was to have the entity class separate from model classes, so each entity could switch or share models as required; so this is a billboard model class, and owner->x/y/z refer to the entity who owns that model's position.

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't seem to work for me. more information is in the first post which I have edited to reflected trying to recreate this code.